How do I use local jars instead of packages in PySpark
I've been following along with the following tutorial:
https://www.romainardiet.com/2023-05-16/iceberg-with-pyspark/
But I've been having trouble getting the spark.sql.extensions and spark.sql.catalog libraries to run.
I'm running Python 3.8 with Spark 3.5.3 and I'm trying to access a Minio S3 bucket through Apache Iceberg.
I work in an environment that doesn't have open internet access so I can't automatically grab the needed packages from Maven.
I've downloaded the needed jars and placed them in the same folder as my Python script.
icberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12-1.6.1.jar
iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12-1.6.1.jar
spark-sql_2.12-3.5_2.12.jar

Here's the code I tried:
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def init_spark():
    conf = SparkConf() \
        .setAppName("Apache Iceberg with PySpark") \
        .setMaster("local[2]") \
        .setAll([
            ("spark.driver.memory", "1g"),
            ("spark.executor.memory", "2g"),
            ("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "40"),
            ("spark.jars", "iceberg-spark-extensions-3.5_2.12-1.6.1.jar"),
            ("spark.jars", "spark-sql_2.12-3.5.2.jar"),
            # Add Iceberg SQL extensions like UPDATE or DELETE in Spark
            ("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions"),

            # Register `my_iceberg_catalog`
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog"),

            # Configure SQL connection to track tables inside `my_iceberg_catalog`
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.jdbc.JdbcCatalog"),
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.uri", "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/iceberg_db"),
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.jdbc.user", "postgres"),
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.jdbc.password", "postgres"),

            # Configure Warehouse on MinIO
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO"),
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.s3.endpoint", "http://minio:9000"),
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.s3.path-style-access", "true"),
            ("spark.sql.catalog.my_iceberg_catalog.warehouse", "s3://warehouse"),
        ])
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

    return spark

I read in the documentation that it's possible to add jars using the spark.jars parameter.
However, when I include the line using spark.sql.extensions I get the error:

Cannot use SparkSessionExtensions to configure session extensions. Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SparkSessionExtensions. I get a similar line with the line inculding "spark.sql.catalog"

When I omit the line including spark.sql.catalog, I later get an error that error:

SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: iceberg. Please find packages at...

